# Azure Quickstart Template Deployment Failing

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment

I'm trying to use [this Azure quickstart template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/ansible-advancedlinux) to deploy Ansible in Azure.

I get so far with the deployment, but then I reach an error when it tries to process these particular extensions...

- installansible
- configuressh

Here is the full error message:

```
{ "status": "Failed", "error": { "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure", "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.", "details": [ { "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError", "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'configuressh'. Error message: \"Enable failed:Incorrect padding\"." } ] } }
```

I have no idea how to fix this, so hopefully someone out there will be able to assist!

Comment: What parameters did you pass in? I'm particularly curious if you are sure the below parameters are correct...

    "customScriptConfigStorageAccountName": {
      "value": ""
    },
    "customScriptConfigStorageAccountKey": {
      "value": ""
    }

Comment: The reason he is asking is due to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/issues/21) issue. Be careful of how you quote variables, It seems that this is the error it gives when it doesn't understand the parameter.

Comment: I don't think it's associated though. It seems like Azure has no idea what installansible and configuressh are?

Answer (score 0):

That version of the template required you to copy all the script files and ssh keys to an Azure Storage account, which is a little bit cumbersome. We just published a new version in which you will only have to upload your private and public ssh key into a private Azure storage account, more info here : http://gonzowins.com/2016/03/23/ansible-azure/ . Before you execute the template, make sure that you have copied the ssh keys into an Azure storage account, the Video explains how to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately it still failed... pastebin.com/aim4N13g

Comment: Hi, having a look to the traces you provided, it looks like you are providing default values for storageAccountName and storageACcountKey. Extracted from the traces I can see  Storage Account Name: namereplacedforprivacyreasons. But before executing the template, you need to place the private and public ssh keys in a private storage account , in a container called ssh and using default names (id_rsa and id_rsa.pub).  Then you need to provide the storage account name and key in the template.  The post http://gonzowins.com/2016/03/23/ansible-azure/  explains this.